# Single selection UITableView overlay cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make custom selection of `UITableView` cells. To do this I created `UIView` above my cell and it appear/disappear on touching now. But the problem is that when I press on cell selection appears. If then I select any other row it will be selected too! But it must not. Every previous cell must be deselected but I do only single selection for my `UITableView`. I'll glad for any help.

Here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"userDataCell";
 AVMThemeCell *cell = [self.userContentTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

 // Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil) {
 cell = [[AVMThemeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
  AVMDataStore *oneItem = [userContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  oneItem = [userContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 [cell setGenre:oneItem];
 cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imgThemesArray[indexPath.row]];



 //save cell state!

 NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)indexPath.row];
 if ([selectedCellsArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",rowNsNum]]  )
 {
     NSLog(@"selectedCellsArray %@",selectedCellsArray);
     cell.selectedBG.hidden=NO;
     [cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
 }
 else
 {

     cell.selectedBG.hidden=YES;

 }


 return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
@try{
    // TODO: Select Item
    if (shareEnabled) {

        [selectedCellsArray removeAllObjects];
        AVMThemeCell *collectionCell = (AVMThemeCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)indexPath.row];

        if ( ![selectedCellsArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",rowNsNum]]  )
        {
            [selectedCellsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];

            collectionCell.selectedBG.hidden = NO;
            [collectionCell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
          //  NSLog(@"view is %@",collectionCell.selectedBG);
            NSLog(@"selected view is hidden = %hhd",collectionCell.hidden);
            NSLog(@"selected in didselect %d",(int)indexPath.row);
        }
        else {
            [selectedCellsArray removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];
            collectionCell.selectedBG.hidden = YES;
           NSLog(@"DEselected in didDEselect");
        }

    }
} @catch (NSException *e){
    NSLog(@"Exception! %@",e);
}



}
```

Comment: Try to remove this line: `[selectedCellsArray removeAllObjects];`. You empty `selectedCellsArray` first, and then check if it contains something, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: By the way, you could save NSNumbers to `selectedCellsArray`. It would be both faster and more convenient. Especially using modern Objective-C syntax: `NSNumber *rowNsNum = @(indexPath.row);`

Comment: @FreeNickname thank you! I solved my problem. I replaced `[selectedCellsArray removeAllObjects];` into condition and then I added `[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];` now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more simple approach to do this is to use `NSIndexPath`.

Create `NSIndexPath` variable to track last selected cell.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

Initialisation variable in `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
self.selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:-1 inSection:-1];
```

Observe value `-1` for row and `-1` for section in above line which will intialize indexPath with no row selection in tableView.

Now, `UITableView` datasource methods will be like below:

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method put a condition to check current indexPath is selected or not?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // . . .

    // Change background color of selected cell

    if (self.selectedIndexPath == indexPath) {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    } else {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }

    // . . .
}
```

Update selected index path in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // . . .

    AVMThemeCell *previousCell = (AVMThemeCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath];
    previousCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    AVMThemeCell *selectedCell = AVMThemeCell *[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath];
    selectedCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    // . . .
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I'll try it though I already solved my problem